# How to write a unit-test case when a boolean changes twice in jasmine-angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a basic function statement which changes boolean state of a variable when response comes in from httpClient.get observable

```
dataLoading:boolean;

testingFunction(){
  this.dataLoading=true;
  getRequest$.subscribe(result=>{
      this.dataLoading=false;
  })
}
```

To test that I created a test case like below which doesn't work.

```
it('Should testingFunction set dataLoading false from true',()=>{
  component.testingFunction();
  expect(component.dataLoading).toBeTrue();
  expect(component.dataLoading).toBeFalse();
});
```

How can I test this change successfully and properly?

Answer (score 1):

Your test doesn't work because it does not synchronize your `expect` calls with the subscription to `getRequest$`.

You can do something like:

```
// use a Subject so we can control emission from getRequest$    
const getRequestSubject = new Subject<string>(); 

// there is probably a better way to wire this up, but unsure of your implementation
service.getRequest$ = getRequestSubject.asObservable(); 

service.testingFunction();

// getRequest$ hasn't emitted yet, so do the 'before' check
expect(service.dataLoading).toBeTrue();  

// force it to emit
getRequestSubject.next('foo'); 
          
// now do the 'after' check
expect(service.dataLoading).toBeFalse();
```